# Error when installing PyObjC on OS X 10.9.3 (Mavericks)

Tags: python

```
pip install -U pyobjc
```

returns

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/1l/tt74p_z93j9d07418vkyrj6c0000gn/T/pip_build_henry/pyobjc-framework-AddressBook
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/henry/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

pip.log is [here](https://gist.github.com/lsfalimis/5e5c0a4727527f25b54f) (it's too long to paste here).

Comment: How did you install pip? - and I think you need to sudo to save to the python site directory

Comment: You need to use sudo on OS X to install Globally via pip or use virtualenv to install locally for a specific project only.